# Using "myself" to change variables

Tags: set, netlogo

I have 200 turtles who can be either sender or receiver of a message and are connected to each other in a random network. I am asking receivers to see if there are senders connected to them and if so, their knowledge value that is a set with 3 values regarding 3 items gets updated with knowledge value of the neighbor added to them.

the problem is `myself` can be easily used to be assigned to a variable, but in my case it cannot be used to change items in a pre-defined set as I encountered an error saying that this was not something I could use set on!

Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
Turtles-own [
knowledgeValue
receiver?
sender?
]
;Network is already constructed and turtles are connected.

to go
ask turtles [
set knowledgeValue []
]

ask turtles [
repeat 3 [
set knowledgeValue lput random-float 1 knowledgeValue
]
]

ask turtles with [receiver?] [ 
       ask (turtles-on neighbors) with [sender?] [ 
           ; the knowledge of receiver gets updated
           set [item 0 [knowledgeValue]] of myself [item 0 [knowledgeValue]] of myself + knowledgeValue
]
]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it this way, here's one option. With this setup:

```
turtles-own [
  knowledgeValue
  receiver?
  sender?
]

to setup 
  ca
  resize-world -3 3 -3 3
  set-patch-size 70
  ask patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set receiver? false
      set sender? false
      ifelse random-float 1 > 0.5 [
        set receiver? true
        set color green
        set knowledgeValue [0 0 0]
      ] [
        set sender? true
        set color red
        set knowledgeValue []
        repeat 3 [
        set knowledgeValue lput random-float 1 knowledgeValue 
        ]
      ]   
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

This generates a world where all `receivers` start with `[0 0 0]` as their `knowledgeValue` list (to prove that `senders` are the ones adding value). Now, have all receivers get their neighbors with `sender?` to `ask` the asking receiver to update that receiver's list. I don't really like this solution but it sort of approaches the issue from the same tack that you outlined.

```
to option-1
  ask turtles with [ receiver? ] [ 
    ; ask senders to ask 'myself' (receiver)
    ask ( turtles-on neighbors ) with [sender?] [       
      ask myself [
        ; note that the second myself (below) actually refers to the 'sender'
        set knowledgeValue replace-item 0 knowledgeValue ( item 0 knowledgeValue + item 0 [knowledgeValue] of myself)
      ]
    ]
  ] 
end
```

One alternative would be to simply sum the values needed and add them directly:

```
to option-2
  ask turtles with [ receiver? ] [
    let my-senders ( turtles-on neighbors ) with [ sender? ] 
    if any? my-senders [
      ; get the sum of their item 0 knowledgeValue
      let to-add sum [ item 0 knowledgeValue ] of my-senders 
      ; add it to the knowledgeValue
      set knowledgeValue replace-item 0 knowledgeValue ( item 0 knowledgeValue + to-add )
    ]
  ]  
end
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining via an example code. I am not sure if I understand some parts. You described correctly that I want to update the values of receivers who are asking senders for some values of them to be added. In other words, having a structure like this `ask A [ ask B [ ...] ]` ,I need to modify A's values by adding things from B. Am I right that this code `set [KnowledgeValue] of myself replace-item 0 [KnowledgeValue] of myself 4` will never work since `myself` does not allow it?

Comment: As far as I know, that is correct- as JenB noted, `[knowledgeValue] of myself` only returns the list value, rather than allowing you to modify the variable itself. It's not the `myself` specifically though, it's the fact that `[variable] of` returns a value. As far as I know, you *also* couldn't do this with `set [knowledgeValue] of one-of turtles [ 1 2 3]` because it would be attempting to modify the reported value.

Comment: I understood. So, let me try to understand how you solved it. In your `setup`, `receivers` are assigned `[0 0 0]` while `senders` `[random random random]`. In option-1, in ask `myself [...]` , are you asking `turtles with [receiver?]` ?  Thanks

Comment: @user710 - More or less- but specifically, the `myself` in `ask myself [ ... ]` refers to the *one* receiver who asked the `senders` defined by the `( turtles-on neighbors ) with [sender?]`. Kind of like: "Receivers, ask all of your neighboring senders to ask you to update your knowledgeValue list." That's why I don't like the solution as much as `option-2`, which I find more straighforward and easy to track.

Comment: Thanks so much. I used ption-1 and it was all I needed to do what I was trying to see.   This note `note that the second myself (below) actually refers to the 'sender'` was awesome! Helped me tremendously! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not `myself`. The problem is that you are trying to `set` a value in a `list`, whereas `set` is used for variables. Have a look at `replace-item` instead.

And you need to do something like `ask myself set ....`

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I actually did use replace-item but as I had an error were trying to modify that. I had this:                                                                                                        `set [KnowledgeValue] of myself replace-item 0 [KnowledgeValue] of myself (item 0 [KnowledgeValue] of myself + item 0 [KnowledgeValue]`                           Why it is still saying it is not something I could use "set" on while I have been using `set XX-set replace-item jk XX-set 0` before                                           Thanks

Comment: Why can't I change an item in a list like this: set [KnowledgeValue] of myself replace-item 0 [KnowledgeValue] of myself 4

Comment: Thanks. Omitting `[]` creates an error saying that `"OF expected this input to be a reporter block, but got anything instead"`. It does not make sense that the items of a list can change but the items of a list of an agent asking other agents cannot be changed!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't thinking. `ask myself set KnowledgeValue replace-item 0 [KnowledgeValue] 4`

Comment: No worries. Thanks so much for the very useful comments.